# Saber se é realmente servidor de cdn

Tags: cdn

Bom dia,

Recentemente, num dos meus websites, o senhor do serviço de hospedagem, propos-me passar o conteudo (videos e imagens) para cdn.
Como sei se realmente passou para cdn?
Como testo, e vejo qual o servidor que me está a fornecer o conteudo?
Existem ferramentas para testar cdn?

Obrigado

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar o comando host no cmd com o nome do site:

host -a www.visitbritain.com

Ele ira retornar:

www.visitbritain.com.   0   IN  CNAME   d18sjq5nyxcof4.cloudfront.net.

Podemos ver que o site usa o d18sjq5nyxcof4.cloudfront.net como CDN.

Comment: Ok, mas como o OP saberia que `d18sjq5nyxcof4.cloudfront.net` se trata de um CDN e não de um desktop no quarto de alguém?

Comment: ele terá o nome do website e poderá checkar na internet se se trata de um serviço cnd.

Comment: Tem como fazer isso em MAC OS?

Comment: Tem que procurar o comando equivalente em mac, vou ver se acho

Comment: Eu ja procurei. Não encontro nada.

Comment: Ve se isso ajuda amigo    
http://osxdaily.com/2015/03/19/detailed-dns-lookup-host-command/

Answer (score 0):

Acessando o site https://www.webpagetest.org/ é possivel realizar o teste.